# Verify JWT token signature with public key in C#

Tags: c#, jwt, rsa

I am not familiar with JWT token and RSA algorithms. I want to generate a JWT token with public and private key by using RSA Algorithm. I need to sign the token with private key and share the public key for other end for them to verify.

I have generated the token by the below code and verified the generated token in JWT.IO site with the public key generated. But it is showing invalid signature.

Kindly assist me on this. Thanks

```cs
using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
{
    //get the public key
    string publicKey = rsa.ToXmlString(false);

    string privateKey = rsa.ToXmlString(true);

    var privateKeyVal = new RsaSecurityKey(rsa);

    byte[] privateKeyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(privateKey);
    string privateKeyPem = Convert.ToBase64String(privateKeyBytes);
    privateKeyPem = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----" + privateKeyPem + "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";

    byte[] publicKeyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(publicKey);
    string publicKeyPem = Convert.ToBase64String(publicKeyBytes);
    publicKeyPem = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----" + publicKeyPem + "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

    var jwttok = new JwtSecurityToken(
    issuer: "iss",
    audience: "aud",
    claims: new List<Claim> { new Claim("user_id", "123") },
    expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
    signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(
        privateKeyVal,
        SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256)
    );

    string token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwttok);
}
```

Token - eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiMTIzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjc0ODI5NDQxLCJpc3MiOiJpc3MiLCJhdWQiOiJhdWQifQ.oh5_Yb8F0wpb5NbqhbpqD_sRc1NnEOEXyEbTJ-AE9266s3bXSaezDT0PAZo_VE7MUnonAbmpVezrPcsRIewcfE3hHNKMWPiYhPaseLyXJTZ-0J8JTyAGXi5aSK_5HITQEEDo_DBW2vnxKocrEmNa0JoQBfAo0TfOysqSj6LCYOI